# Refresh passport.js session data using req.login()

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

I'm using passport.js. The problem is when I change user information such as user name, It's not changed until user re-login. If user logout and login again, the information changed. but I want to change in the session without re-logging in.

My deserializeUser function like below, It looks different original passport's example because it is pickup data from session instead of querying database. I want to up loading speed so I didn't use database query on deserialize function.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(userSession, done){

    var member = { id : userSession[0], name : userSession[1] };
    done(null, member);

});
```

So I think I have to use `req.login()` like below, but the session wouldn't changed.

```
Members.findOne({_id : someId }, function(err, member){
    member[username] = req.body.username;
    member.save(function (err){
        if(err) return next();

        console.log('The original session :'+req.sessionId);

        req.login(req.user, {}, function(err){
            if (err) return next();

            console.log('The new session :'+req.sessionId);
            res.send(200);
        });

    })
})
```

The problem is original session and new session is same, How can I force to refresh `req.user` object?

I red this document but didn't get solution.
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/208

Comment: I think the `req.user` object is created for convenience in some middleware from the `req.session.passport.user` object. You could try changing that one to see if it persists. Also, it looks like the method is `logIn` and not `login` (see [here](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate))

Comment: @Barnab `req.login()` and `req.logIn()` are the same: "Passport exposes a login() function on req (also aliased as logIn()) that can be used to establish a login session." (from the same docs).